# Wordpress Articles Page Edition

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I have a wordpress webiste and when I got into my articles page, where it shows every article, it is very awful because all the articles show their entire content. And also in the title it shows the html tags.

Here's the example link: https://nauticoleiria.pt/category/provas/

As you can see every article shows the whole content of it and the title has the html tags.

What I want to do is to remove the HTML tags from the title.
Also in all the articles I want to not show the content.[[Example of what should be happening]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqoVc.png)
I only want it to show like in the example above.

How can I do it? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can turn to a freelance exchange, where experts will correct your headlines for a small fee.